# Is there a way to obtain the logical index of a row in Handsontable

Tags: javascript, handsontable

The Handsontable [sorting documentation](http://docs.handsontable.com/0.20.0/demo-sorting-data.html) shows how you can obtain a physical index given a logical index:

> So I want to get the physical index, having the logical index. This is the code I have to write:
>
> physicalIndex = instance.sortIndex[logicalIndex][0];
>
> The revers mapping is a bit more complicated, but is also possible. In fact, columnSorting plugin has two dedicated methods which translates logical indices to physical and vice versa (called translateRow() and untranslateRow()) but they are currently inaccessible from the global scope.

A mention of the reverse is made, but it doesn't say how this can be achieved.  Can someone explain how this can be done using the public API of Handsontable?

Comment: so you want the logical index given the physical index? just a random question but what's the use case of that?

Comment: @ZekeDroid That's correct, I want the logical index given the physical.  I have a sorted HOT that I've turned off observeChanges for.  I'm attempting to use the setDataAtRowProp function, but need the logical index to update a cell.

Comment: Ah see that's what I thought. Pretty sure you need the physical index, not the logical one. The logical one is only used for displaying things so you can should pass in the physical one into `setDataAtRowProp`. I might be wrong but give it a try.

Comment: I tried out setDataAtRowProp, but unfortunately it looks like it requires the logical index rather than the physical index.